# passing value to array from api php

Tags: php

I want to pass value from API to array but I am not able to figureout what code I need to write. currently it returns [1481367,7546218] how can I pass this in array

```
$content = array($result) ;
```

Below is the API Code

```
$Login = 8632465; #Must be Changed
$apiPassword = "Kcfve123*"; #Must be Changed
$data = array("Login" => $Login, "Password" => $apiPassword);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://client-api.instaforex.com/api/Authentication/RequestPartnerApiToken');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$apiMethodUrl = 'partner/GetReferralAccounts/'; #possibly Must be Changed
$parameters = $Login; #possibly Must be Changed. Depends on the method param 
$ch = curl_init('http://client-api.instaforex.com/'.$apiMethodUrl.$parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); # Turn it ON to get result to the variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('passkey: '.$token));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//$result = trim(preg_replace('[]','',curl_exec($ch)));
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CURL result is "[1481367,7546218]", then to convert this into an array:

```
`$content = json_decode($result,TRUE); //Here $result = "[1481367,7546218]"`
```

Printing the variable `$content` using `var_dump()` variable will output:

`array(2) {
  [0] => int(1481367)
  [1] => int(7546218)
}`

Comment: Can you please try adding json_decode when I am doing echo of $content it is giving [1481367,7546218]1  ?

Comment: when I am doing downloding api data into file with code file_put_contents('c:/xampp/htdocs/upload/test.txt', $result);  I am getting value as 1 only why. When I echo $result I get [1481367,7546218]1

Comment: Just change the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`